# c# - Read file with irregular newline characters

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to read a text file with C#, that is formatted like this:

```
this is a line\r\n
this is a line\r
\r\n
this is a line\r
\r\n
this is a line\r
\r\n
this is a line\r\n
this is a line\r
\r\n
etc...
```

I am reading each line from the file with

```
StreamReader.ReadLine()
```

but that does not preserve new line characters. I need to know/detect what kind of new line characters there are because I am counting the amount of bytes on each line. For example:

if the the line ends with character `\r`, line consists of: `((nr-of-bytes-in-line) + 1 byte)` bytes (depending on the encoding type of course), if line ends with `\r\n`, line consists of: `((nr-of-bytes-in-line) + 2 bytes)` bytes.

**EDIT:**

I have the solution, based on the answer of **israel altar**. BTW: **Jon Skeet** suggested it also. I have implemented an overridden version of ReadLine, so that it would include new line characters. This is the code of the overridden function:

```
    public override String ReadLine()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            int ch = Read();
            if (ch == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
            {
                if (ch == '\r' && Peek() == '\n')
                {
                    sb.Append('\r');
                    sb.Append('\n');
                    Read();
                    break;
                }
                else if(ch == '\r' && Peek() == '\r')
                {
                    sb.Append('\r');
                    break;
                }
            }
            sb.Append((char)ch);
        }
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I believe you'll basically have to reimplement `ReadLine()` yourself in that case then.

Comment: Do use ReadLine.  Read one character at a time if you need to byte count.

Comment: No I do it like this: `string line = sr.ReadLine(); int nrOfBytes = Encoding.GetByteCount(line);` But need to detect what kind of new line chars there are.. either `\r` or `\r\n`. So that I could do: `nrOfBytes += Encoding.GetByteCount(UNKNOWN-NEW-LINE-CHAR);`

Comment: This will help to implement it: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068,references

Comment: Use `Stream`, not `StreamReader`, because you need to deal with bytes. All `TextReader`s, including `StreamReader`, help you proces lines at the expense of making it impossible for you to access the raw bytes separating them.

Comment: So is there an additional `\n` between the first and second lines of your sample text? Or did you just format it that way when posting it?

Comment: Yes some lines end with these characters: `\r\n`. But most lines end like this: `\r`. And the next line will be only this: `\r\n`.

Comment: Does your example text have 10 lines then? And what counts should be returned for each line? You need to be more explicit - things are a bit ambiguous at the moment. Can you put a single string containing all the data without putting extra line breaks in it, because I can't tell what's in the data and what's in the formatting you used when posting. Ideally, give us a list of hex byte values.

Comment: What's particularly confusing is that you have `\n` in your sample string along with additional line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the way that readline is implemented according to .net resources:

```
// Reads a line. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by
        // a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return
        // immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not
        // contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned
        // value is null if the end of the input stream has been reached.
        //
        public virtual String ReadLine() 
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (true) {
                int ch = Read();
                if (ch == -1) break;
                if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') 
                {
                    if (ch == '\r' && Peek() == '\n') Read();
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
                sb.Append((char)ch);
            }
            if (sb.Length > 0) return sb.ToString();
            return null;
        }
```

as you can see you can add an if sentence like this:

```
 if (ch == '\r') 
{
  //add the amount of bytes wanted
}
if  (ch == '\n')
{
  //add the amount of bytes wanted
}
```

or do whatever manipulation you want.

Comment: Or just change it to append the `\r` and `\n` to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I am going to try this, I will have to implement my own version of ReadLine (an overridden version).

Comment: I have implemented an overridden version of ReadLine in a custom class, I think it works. I am testing what the best way is to get the byte count of a line, but this is the solution I was looking for.